# Backbonejs: .on vs .listenTo vs .bind

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, callback

What are the differences among `.on`, .`listenTo`, and `.bind`?

I tested them here and they seem do the same thing: a callback.

```
var NewStatusView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "submit form": "addStatus"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {

        // using .on
        //this.collection.on("add", this.clearInput, this);

        // or using bind: 
        //_.bindAll(this, 'addStatus', 'clearInput');
        //this.collection.bind('add', this.clearInput);

        // or using listenTo: 
         _.bindAll(this, 'addStatus', 'clearInput');
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.clearInput) ;
    },

    addStatus: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.collection.create({ text: this.$('textarea').val() });
    },

    clearInput: function() {
        this.$('textarea').val('');
    }
});
```

When and in scenario to use which is the best?

Comment: Have you read the documentation or the source code? See https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L233

Comment: Have you visited the linked page on github?

Comment: `Events.bind   = Events.on;Events.unbind = Events.off;` does it mean that `bind` is the same as `on`?

Comment: Yes, both methods do the same thing. Check the first line http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's usually best to use [`listenTo()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)

From [Backbone Essentials](https://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/#listento-and-stoplistening) by Addy Osmani:

> While `on()` and `off()` add callbacks directly to an observed object,
>   `listenTo()` tells an object to listen for events on another object,
>   allowing the listener to keep track of the events for which it is
>   listening. `stopListening()` can subsequently be called on the listener
>   to tell it to stop listening for events:
>
> ```
> var a = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
> var b = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
> var c = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
>
> // add listeners to A for events on B and C
> a.listenTo(b, 'anything', function(event){ console.log("anything happened"); });
> a.listenTo(c, 'everything', function(event){ console.log("everything happened"); });
>
> // trigger an event
> b.trigger('anything'); // logs: anything happened
>
> // stop listening
> a.stopListening();
>
> // A does not receive these events
> b.trigger('anything');
> c.trigger('everything');
> ```
>
> If you use on and off and remove views and their corresponding models
>   at the same time, there are generally no problems. But a problem
>   arises when you remove a view that had registered to be notified about
>   events on a model, but you don’t remove the model or call off to
>   remove the view’s event handler. Since the model has a reference to
>   the view’s callback function, the JavaScript garbage collector cannot
>   remove the view from memory. This is called a ghost view and is a form
>   of memory leak which is common since the models generally tend to
>   outlive the corresponding views during an application’s lifecycle. For
>   details on the topic and a solution, check this excellent article by
>   Derick Bailey.
>
> Practically, every `on` called on an object also requires an `off` to be
>   called in order for the garbage collector to do its job. `listenTo()`
>   changes that, allowing Views to bind to Model notifications and unbind
>   from all of them with just one call - `stopListening()`.
>
> The default implementation of `View.remove()` makes a call to
>   `stopListening()`, ensuring that any listeners bound using `listenTo()`
>   are unbound before the view is destroyed.
>
> ```
> var view = new Backbone.View();
> var b = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
>
> view.listenTo(b, 'all', function(){ console.log(true); });
> b.trigger('anything');  // logs: true
>
> view.listenTo(b, 'all', function(){ console.log(false); });
> view.remove(); // stopListening() implicitly called
> b.trigger('anything');  // does not log anything
> ```

Comment: I didn't upvote because no mention of bind! I don't care for the use of bind because there's the mental namespace conflict with _.bind and _.bindAll, why Jeremy did you choose bind for Events also